# consolidate an account c# doesn't work

Tags: c#

I have two accounts that might be consolidated into a new checking account. this should create new checking account with the sum of 2 balances. 
I have a code :

```
public void ConsolidateAccounts(int accountNumber1, int accountNumber2) 
{
    if (accountNumber1 == accountNumber2)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Same accounts can not be consolidated");
    }
    else 
    {
        int newAccountNumber = 0;
        var newAccount = new Checking(newAccountNumber, (accountNumber1.balance + accountNumber2.balance));
    }
}
```

this is my account class:

```
class Account
{
    private readonly int _accountNumber;
    protected double balance;
    public AccountStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Account() { }
    public Account(int accountNumber, double balance)
    {
        this._accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

I have more methods in account class but I Dont need them for this question.

The question is, how to specify balance for accountNumber1 and accountNumber2, because  balance get highlighted red. I am not sure how to access balance.

```
(accountNumber1.balance + accountNumber2.balance)
```

Comment: Brendan pretty much covered it, but I'd like to mention that traditionally you'd use `decimal` for an account balance so that any rounding errors are base-10. The suffix for a decimal literal is even an `M` (for money).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing in an `int` (I presume the account id's) to your function, rather than `Account` instances.

The first thing we need to do is expose the Account Id in your `Account` class:

```
public int AccountId => _accountNumber;
```

Then we need to fix the `Balance` property (it doesn't get set by the constructor):

```
public double Balance
{
    get => this.balance;
    private set => this.balance = value;
}
```

Then we can change the method like this:

```
public void ConsolidateAccounts(Account account1, Account account2) 
{
    if (account1.AccountNumber == account2.AccountNumber)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Same accounts can not be consolidated");
     }
     else 
     {
         int newAccountNumber = 0;
         var newAccount = new Checking(newAccountNumber, (account1.Balance + account2.Balance));
     }
}
```

Comment: May want to note that the Balance auto-property is not being wired up to the backing field.

Comment: Ah yes I missed that.